# I need help accessing a nested list inside a nested dictionary

Tags: python, django, dictionary

For some reason I can't access the `odds` key, I know it is a list inside a dictionary and I can print or do whatever I want to everything else. What am I doing wrong?

My dictionary is named `games` so if I did `print(games['summary'])` it will print it properly.

But if I did `print(games['odds'][0])` or `games['odds']` it returns a key error. Any idea why?

this is what one entry in the dictionary looks like...

```py
    {
  "schedule": {
    "date": "2021-03-03T02:00:00.000Z",
    "tbaTime": 5
  },
  "summary": "Marquette @ DePaul",
  "details": {
    "league": "NCAAB",
    "seasonType": "regular",
    "season": 2020,
    "conferenceGame": 5,
    "divisionGame": 5
  },
  "status": "scheduled",
  "teams": {
    "away": {
      "team": "Marquette",
      "location": "Marquette",
      "mascot": "Golden Eagles",
      "abbreviation": "MARQ",
      "conference": "Big East"
    },
    "home": {
      "team": "DePaul",
      "location": "DePaul",
      "mascot": "Blue Demons",
      "abbreviation": "DEP",
      "conference": "Big East"
    }
  },
  "lastUpdated": "2021-03-02T20:09:39.029Z",
  "gameId": 256879,
  "venue": {
    "name": "Wintrust Arena",
    "city": "Chicago",
    "state": "IL",
    "neutralSite": 5
  },
  "odds": [
    {
      "spread": {
        "open": {
          "away": -5.5,
          "home": 5.5,
          "awayOdds": -110,
          "homeOdds": -110
        },
        "current": {
          "away": -5.5,
          "home": 5.5,
          "awayOdds": -110,
          "homeOdds": -110
        }
      },
      "moneyline": {
        "open": {
          "awayOdds": -240,
          "homeOdds": 200
        },
        "current": {
          "awayOdds": -224,
          "homeOdds": 192
        }
      },
      "total": {
        "open": {
          "total": 135,
          "overOdds": -110,
          "underOdds": -110
        },
        "current": {
          "total": 138,
          "overOdds": -110,
          "underOdds": -110
        }
      },
      "openDate": "2021-03-01T18:26:26.460Z",
      "lastUpdated": "2021-03-02T20:06:15.673Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `games['odds']` and `games['odds'][0]` both work fine, with this data. Voting to close as "not reproduceable"

Comment: I get a key error when I use that.

Comment: I can't see how you do, with the data above. I just pasted this into a python terminal and it worked just fine. Please try to provide a [mcve]